# How to break or Exit from Linq query

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I need to find the 1st matching record between 2 generic Lists.
Below is the code I have written. But, even after a match is obtained, it is still processing further records. Is there any way to break from the below query? Something like "break" or "Exit for"

```
     foreach (var itemOld in oldList)
        {
            var result = (from itemNew in newList
                          where itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id
                          select itemNew).ToList();

            // Do processing
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Both the inner and outer query will terminate as soon as a matching item is found:

```
foreach (var itemOld in oldList)
{
        var result = (from itemNew in newList
                      where itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id
                      select itemNew).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            // process result
            break;
        }
}
```

You can also combine them like this:

```
var result = (from itemNew in newList
              from itemOld in oldList
              where itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id
              select itemNew).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    // process result
}
```

The difference is that the first approach will go through `newList` repeatedly until a match is found. The second will go through `oldList` repeatedly until a match is found.

To address your comment below, if you want to process all the matches, just remove the `break` from the first example, or do this for the second version:

```
var results = from itemNew in newList
              from itemOld in oldList
              where itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id
              select itemNew;

foreach (var item in results)
{
    // process item
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe , how about using TakeWhile to achieve this?

Comment: @TanimaKumari I don't think that would really be of any help here. `.FirstOrDefault()` will stop lookng for results as soon as it finds one, so that's really all you need.

Comment: Got it, thanks again. A second question: If there are more than one matching records, then will we use "ToList" only or any other keyword?

Comment: @TanimaKumari I've edited my answer to address your newest question.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is [break;](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

```
 foreach (var itemOld in oldList)
        {
            var result = (from itemNew in newList
                          where itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id
                          select itemNew).ToList();

            if(someThingisTrue){
               break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will needlessly iterate the results on account of `.ToList()`.

Comment: @JLRishe - the OP stated that he needs the information from result in order to determine whether he should stay in the loop or not.  I don't have enough information to determine if there would be more than one element returned from the LINQ query.

Comment: OP has stated that she wants to find the first matching record between the two lists. Therefore she just needs one item, not a whole list.

Comment: @JLRishe - As far as I know, `.ToList()` does not cause any iterating of the list you are calling that on.  However, it will force immediate execution of the query and the results to be cached.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: For the majority of cases, `.ToList()` will cause the entire original set to be iterated (potentially multiple times), even if there's no need to, and this is true in your case. Observe: http://ideone.com/371TK2 The `.FirstOrDefault()` approach stops as soon as it finds the value it's looking for, while the `.ToList()` approach iterates the entire original set.

Comment: @JLRishe - iterating and retrieving the entire list from the database are two different things.  I assumed you meant it would iterate (like a for loop).  Yes, `.toList()` will retrieve the entire list of all matches.  In any case, I would assume that `itemNew.Id == itemOld.Id` is only going to return 0 or 1 results (primary key match). Lastly, nice example and site!  I can see that coming in handy :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

```
var predicate = itemNew => oldList.FirstOrDefault(itemOld => itemOld.Id == itemNew.Id);

var result = newList.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out in the comments, I did stuff in the wrong order =(.  Fixed for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but you can do it with a join:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var oldList = new List<Item>();

        oldList.Add(new Item() { Id = 3 });
        oldList.Add(new Item() { Id = 4 });
        oldList.Add(new Item() { Id = 5 });

        var newList = new List<Item>();

        newList.Add(new Item() { Id = 1 });
        newList.Add(new Item() { Id = 2 });
        newList.Add(new Item() { Id = 3 });

        // here is the linq join
        var result = 
            newList.Join(
                oldList, 
                item => item.Id, 
                item => item.Id, 
                (itemNew, itemOld) => itemNew).FirstOrDefault();

        // outputs 3
        Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
    }
}
```